# Div Hover not working in IE 6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, mousehover

What is the trick or way to show hovers in IE 6.0?

Other Browsers like Firefox, Chrome and Safari show DIV Hovers, while IE 6.0 do not.

Is there any JScript way to do so? If so then could some one give me a link or a code snippet from which I might build a work around for IE 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [csshover.htc](http://xref.moodle.org/lib/csshover.htc.source.txt)

Along with this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><style type="text/css"> body { behavior: url(csshover.htc) }</style><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

IE6 does not support the `hover` style on any element other than `<a>` tags.

Fortunately however, there are plenty of hacks to make it work.

The best one is [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html). Simply add the reference to the script to the top of your CSS file, as per the instructions on the site, and all your hovers will start working.

Hope that helps.